# Could not find package 2.2.3

Tags: upgrade, composer, magento2.2.2

When updating from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3 with

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 --no-update
```

I get this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package magento/product-community-edition in a version match
  ing 2.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked this and I couldn't reproduce your error. Could you maybe extend your question with more details. Like what you've done already. If you have this with both an existing project and a clean Magento 2.2.2 installation?

Comment: before i ran this command , let me cant from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3 now, how can i fix it. thank you
composer remove sjparkinson/static-review
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

getting this now
[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package magento/product-community-edition in a version match ing 2.2.3

Comment: updated @aArjenMiedema